# Django order of message tags

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I wonder if it is possible to change the order of the message tags of a django message with extra tags.

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'success message', extra_tags='safe')
```

And in my template I use

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
     {% if 'safe' in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{% else %}{{ message }}{% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

With this the class of the div will be:

```
<div class="alert alert-safe success">
```

but I want to have the two tags switched, so that I can use the bootstrap class.

```
<div class="alert alert-success safe">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tags` property is defined in the `Message` class and hardcodes the order. I think it would be tricky to change it.

An alernative would be to use `{{ message.level_tag }}` and `{{ message.extra_tags }}` in your template instead of `{{ message.tags }}`.

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.level_tag }} {{ message.extra_tags|default_if_none:'' }}">
```

If you're not using the `safe` class in your `CSS`, you might be able to remove the `{{ message.extra_tags|default_if_none:'' }}` part.

An alternative approach would be to use a method like [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) or [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) in the view:

```
messages.success(request, mark_safe('success message'))
```

Then you won't need to check `message.extra_tags` in the template:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
   {{ message }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{ message.level_tag }}` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!